# Using generics and Class of an object in map

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have following class/interface structure (can't modify the source):

```java
public interface Car {}

public class CarA implements Car{
    public String getASpecifics() {...}
}

public class CarB implements Car{
    public String getBSpecifics() {...}
}

public class Summary {...}
```

I want to have a generic way of creating `Summray` for concrete implementations of `Car` interface which will be open to adding new implementations. My approach is following:

```java
public CarSummarizer {
    public interface SummaryGenerator<T extends Car> {
        Summary generateSummary(T car);
    }

    static {
        SummaryGenerator<CarA> aGen = c -> {... c.getASpecifics(); ...}
        SummaryGenerator<CarB> bGen = c -> {... c.getBSpecifics(); ...}
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to store `aGen` and `bgen` in a `Map`. I want to parametrize it so that I can offer one only public static method which accepts `Car car` and based on it's class object (`car.getClass()`) uses correct `SummaryGenerator` implemenation. That should look something like following:

```java
public static Summary getSummaryForCar(Car car) {
     return map.get(car.getClass()).generateSummary(car);
}
```

I don't know how to declare and instantiate that `Map` so that it's fully type-safe (i.e. doesn't allow inserting pair `(CarC.class, SummaryGenerator<CarD>)`). I'd like something like this:

```java
public static <T extends Car> Map<Class<T>, SummaryGenerator<T>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

static {
    // after instantiation
    map.put(CarA.class, aGen);
    map.put(CarB.class, BGen);
}

// also support following
public static <T extends Car> void addSummaryGenerator(T car, SummaryGenerator<T> sg) {
    map.put(car.getClass(), sg);
}
```

That doesn't work because generics can't be declared on variables like they can be on functions.
I guess I could define new class `public class SummarizerStorage<T extends Car>` and the place map inside and just delegate calls. That seems like an overkill and ugly. I feel like it should be done somehow directly.

Declaring map like `Map<Class<? extends Car>, SummaryGenerator<? extends Car>>` would allow paring of `Class<>` and `SummaryGenerator<>` of sibling types. I want to allow only same type pairs.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to achieve compile-time type safety. You probably need to just validate, which implies runtime.

Comment: Ok. But even if i assume saftey, and use map declaration with wildcard, method `getSummaryForCar` still doesn't compile. Compiler says `return map.get(car.getClass()).generateSummary(car); reason: argument mismatch; T#1 cannot be converted to CAP#1
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Car declared in method <T#1>getSummaryForCar(T#1)
    T#2 extends Car declared in interface SummaryGenerator
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Car from capture of ? extends Car
`

Comment: I see a contradiction in your requirements. You said you want to only allow same type pairs, but you also want to support `addSummaryGenerator(T car, SummaryGenerator<T> sg)`. That is the exact opposite of "only allow same type pairs". Suppose `CarC` is a subtype of `CarB`. I can then do `addSummaryGenerator(new CarC(), bGen)` to pair a summary generator for `CarB` with the class `CarC`. Is that intended?

Comment: True, code in question doesn't comply with my requirements. That's why I said I'm not sure how to declare generics. Is it possible to somehow bind those two `T`'s in function signature without runtime check? I'm also open to bigger refactoring of code to get desired functionality. I just want it to be comiple-time type-safe and meet descriptive requirements, doesn't have to be the way I wrote it in question

Comment: @Sweper , actualy, yes it's ok with `CarC` as subtype of `CarB` because `bGen` would be able to handle it. What I don't want to allow is `addSummaryGenerator(new CarA(), bGen)` because that would break if I then called `getSummaryForCar(new CarA())`. Would then signature like this prevent breaking `public static <T extends Car, T2 extends T> void addSummaryGenerator(T car, SummaryGenerator<T2> sg)`? But still, my main concern is that compilation error in `getSummaryForCar` from few comments above

Answer (score 0):

You can do this *with compile-time safety* if you wrap your map and only allow to put entries of which the value `SummaryGenerator<T>` matches a key of `Class<T>`. To get the `SummaryGenerator` you need to cast but since you ensured that you only added entries that actually can be cast to `SummaryGenerator<T>`, this is safe to do. If you try to add an incompatible `SummaryGenerator` for a given implementation of `Car`, it would result in a compile error.

```java
public class SummaryGeneratorStorage {

    private static final Map<Class<? extends Car>, CarSummarizer.SummaryGenerator<? extends Car>> map = new HashMap<>();

    // provides type safety to only add a SummaryGenerator<T> for a key of Class<T>
    public static <T extends Car> void add(Class<T> clazz, CarSummarizer.SummaryGenerator<T> sg) {
        map.put(clazz, sg);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Car> CarSummarizer.SummaryGenerator<T> get(T car) {
        // this cast is safe since the add-method only
        // allows a SummaryGenerator<T> to be added for a key of Class<T>
        return (CarSummarizer.SummaryGenerator<T>) map.get(car.getClass());
    }

    private SummaryGeneratorStorage() { }
}
```

In order to get a `Summary`, you retrieve the registered `SummaryGenerator` for the `Car` and call the implemented `generateSummary` method. If no `SummaryGenerator` is found for the passed implementation of `Car`, just throw an exception or handle it a different way.  Note that the signature of `add` takes a `Class` and not a `Car` object since we don't need an instance at this point to make the reference to an implementation of `Car`.

```java
public class CarSummarizer {

    public interface SummaryGenerator<T extends Car> {
        Summary generateSummary(T car);
    }

    static {
        // here you cannot pass incompatible implementations of Car (compile-time safety)
        SummaryGenerator<CarA> aGen = c -> new Summary(c.getASpecifics());
        SummaryGeneratorStorage.add(CarA.class, aGen); // with variable
        SummaryGeneratorStorage.add(CarB.class, c -> new Summary(c.getBSpecifics())); // direct
    }

    public static <T extends Car> Summary getSummary(T car) {
        SummaryGenerator<T> generator = SummaryGeneratorStorage.get(car);
        if (generator != null) {
            return generator.generateSummary(car);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no summary generator found");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a test class for the above code. A simple `Summary` containing a *name*-field was used and the implementations of `Car` return A, B or C in their `getXSpecifics()` methods:

```java
public class CarSummarizerTest {

    @Test
    public void testCarA() {
        CarA car = new CarA();
        Summary summary = CarSummarizer.getSummary(car);
        Assert.assertEquals(car.getASpecifics(), summary.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCarB() {
        CarB car = new CarB();
        Summary summary = CarSummarizer.getSummary(car);
        Assert.assertEquals(car.getBSpecifics(), summary.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCarC() {
        CarC car = new CarC();
        Assert.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            CarSummarizer.getSummary(car);
        });
    }
}
```

For completeness the other classes:

```java
public class CarA implements Car {
    public String getASpecifics() { return "A"; }
}

public class CarB implements Car {
    public String getBSpecifics() { return "B"; }
}

public class CarC implements Car {
    public String getCSpecifics() { return "C"; }
}

public class Summary {
    private final String name;
    public Summary(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid wrapper class, but I guess I'll have to make it. With your solution I could still do `SummaryGeneratorStorage.map.put(CarB.class, aGen);` in static block and break the code with `CarSummarizer.getSummary(new CarB())`. If I control myself in static block and only add pairs using `add` method then wrapper class isn't needed anymore. For full solution wrapper class shouldn't be nested class. Also, you've changed signature of add method from `add(T car, SummaryGenerator<T> sg)`  to `add(Class<T> clazz, SummaryGenerator<T> sg)` but that's not that relevant.

Comment: @crnjo I updated my answer. Certainly you would have been able access the map since the class was nested... Now the `SummaryGeneratorStorage` is not a nested class anymore which adds another safety. Additionally, you can consider making the storage package-private. The signature of `add` was changed on purpose (and an explanation added in the answer) since at this point you don't want to instantiate implementations of `Car` just to pass the class.